# Trouble accessing public methods in class A from class B

Tags: java, class, methods

I have two classes, class A and Class B.

```
public class A {
    B testB = new B();
    testB.setName("test"); //**Error Syntax error on token(s), misplaced constructs
                           //**(same line above) Error Syntax error on "test"
}

//in a separate file
public class B {
    public String name;
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Why can't I access this function "setName" in class B within Class A? Thanks.

Comment: Put that code in an init function which you call in a constructor or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the function from within another method or a constructor.

```
    public class A {

      //Constructor
      public A(){
        B testB = new B();
        testB.setName("test");
      }

      //Method
      public void setup(){

        B testB = new B();
        testB.setName("test"); 
       }
    }

    /*Then in a main method or some other class create an instance of A 
and call the setup method.*/

    A a = new A();
    a.setup();
```

Comment: I must be too tired because for some reason I couldn't realize this simple mistake. Thanks, i'll accept the answer when it lets me.

Comment: Glad I could help, we have all been there keep plugging away.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put that code inside the `A`'s constructor...

```
public A() {
    B testB = new B();
    testB.setName("test");
}
```

...and then instantiate it.

```
A someA = new A();
```

Comment: Shouldn't the signature of the constructor be public A(){}

Comment: @kmb385 I removed the `void`.

Answer (score 0):

```
testB.setName("test");
```

is a statement and needs to be in a code block. At present it it in the class block where non-declarative statements are not allowed.

So moving this statent into a constructor, method or initializer block will fix the problem:

```
public class A {
   B testB = new B(); // B can remain here

   public A() {
     testB.setName("test");
   }
}
```